# Draw hole on UIBlurEffect

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, overlay, layer

**Xcode 8.0 - Swift 2.3**
I have an internal extension to create blur layer that works great:

```
internal extension UIView {
    
    /**
     Add and display on current view a blur effect.
     */
    internal func addBlurEffect(style style: UIBlurEffectStyle = .ExtraLight, atPosition position: Int = -1) -> UIView {
        // Blur Effect
        let blurEffectView = self.createBlurEffect(style: style)
        if position >= 0 {
            self.insertSubview(blurEffectView, atIndex: position)
        } else {
            self.addSubview(blurEffectView)
        }
        return blurEffectView
    }
 
    internal func createBlurEffect(style style: UIBlurEffectStyle = .ExtraLight) -> UIView {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: style)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = self.bounds
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        return blurEffectView
    }
    
}
```

Question is: how can I add a shaped hole in blur overlay?
I have made many attempts:

```
let p = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.viewBlur!.frame.width, self.viewBlur!.frame.height), cornerRadius: 0.0)
p.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
let f = CAShapeLayer()
f.fillColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
f.opacity = 0.5
f.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
p.appendPath(self.holePath)
f.path = p.CGPath
self.viewBlur!.layer.addSublayer(f)
```

but result is:

[image]

I can't understand why hole is ok on `UIVisualEffectView` but not in `_UIVisualEffectBackdropView`

### UPDATE

I've tryied @Arun solution (with UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark), but result is not the same:

[image]

### UPDATE 2

With @Dim_ov's solution I have:
[image]

In order to make this work I need to hide `_UIVisualEffectBackdropView`in this way:

```
    for v in effect.subviews {
        if let filterView = NSClassFromString("_UIVisualEffectBackdropView") {
            if v.isKindOfClass(filterView) {
                v.hidden = true
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In iOS 10 you have to use `mask` property of `UIVisualEffectView` instead of `CALayer`'s `mask`.

I saw this covered in the release notes for some early betas of iOS 10 or Xcode 8, but I can not find those notes now :). I'll update my answer with a proper link as soon as I find it.

So here is the code that works in iOS 10/Xcode 8:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var blurView: UIVisualEffectView!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        updateBlurViewHole()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        updateBlurViewHole()
    }

    func updateBlurViewHole() {
        let maskView = UIView(frame: blurView.bounds)
        maskView.clipsToBounds = true;
        maskView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        let outerbezierPath = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: blurView.bounds, cornerRadius: 0)
        let rect = CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 100, height: 100)
        let innerCirclepath = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect:rect, cornerRadius:rect.height * 0.5)
        outerbezierPath.append(innerCirclepath)
        outerbezierPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = true

        let fillLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        fillLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
        fillLayer.fillColor = UIColor.green.cgColor // any opaque color would work
        fillLayer.path = outerbezierPath.cgPath
        maskView.layer.addSublayer(fillLayer)

        blurView.mask = maskView;
    }
}
```

Swift 2.3 version:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var blurView: UIVisualEffectView!

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        updateBlurViewHole()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        updateBlurViewHole()
    }

    func updateBlurViewHole() {
        let maskView = UIView(frame: blurView.bounds)
        maskView.clipsToBounds = true;
        maskView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        let outerbezierPath = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: blurView.bounds, cornerRadius: 0)
        let rect = CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 100, height: 100)
        let innerCirclepath = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect:rect, cornerRadius:rect.height * 0.5)
        outerbezierPath.appendPath(innerCirclepath)
        outerbezierPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = true

        let fillLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        fillLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
        fillLayer.fillColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
        fillLayer.path = outerbezierPath.CGPath
        maskView.layer.addSublayer(fillLayer)

        blurView.maskView = maskView
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Well, it was Apple Developer forums discussion and not iOS release notes. But there are answers from Apple's representatives so I think, this information may be considered "official".

A link to the discussion: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50854#157782

> Masking the layer of a visual effect view is not guaranteed to produce
>   the correct results – in some cases on iOS 9 it would produce an
>   effect that looked correct, but potentially sourced the wrong content.
>   Visual effect view will no longer source the incorrect content, but
>   the only supported way to mask the view is to either use cornerRadius
>   directly on the visual effect view’s layer (which should produce the
>   same result as you are attempting here) or to use the visual effect
>   view’s maskView property.

[image]

Comment: @LucaDavanzo, I have added Swift 2.3 version that works perfectly for me (iOS 10.1). Can you share a screenshot of your non-working version?

Comment: I updated question with screenshot and a hack/solution

Comment: Btw thanks to point me to the solution, I'll wait for links ,)

Comment: @LucaDavanzo, added the link. Sorry for the delay. This was discussed at the Apple Dev forums rather than in release notes. That's why I couldn't find it for so long

Answer (score 3):

Please check my code here

internal extension UIView {

```
/**
 Add and display on current view a blur effect.
 */
internal func addBlurEffect(style style: UIBlurEffectStyle = .ExtraLight, atPosition position: Int = -1) -> UIView {
    // Blur Effect
    let blurEffectView = self.createBlurEffect(style: style)
    if position >= 0 {
        self.insertSubview(blurEffectView, atIndex: position)
    } else {
        self.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    }
    return blurEffectView
}

internal func createBlurEffect(style style: UIBlurEffectStyle = .ExtraLight) -> UIView {
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: style)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = self.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
    return blurEffectView
}
```

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var blurView: UIImageView!

var blurEffectView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    blurEffectView = blurView.addBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light, atPosition: 0)


}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let outerbezierPath = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: self.blurEffectView.frame, cornerRadius: 0)
    let rect = CGRectMake(150, 150, 100, 100)
    let innerCirclepath = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect:rect, cornerRadius:rect.height * 0.5)
    outerbezierPath.appendPath(innerCirclepath)
    outerbezierPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = false
    let fillLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    fillLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
    fillLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    fillLayer.path = outerbezierPath.CGPath
    self.blurEffectView.layer.mask = fillLayer
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}
With UIBlurEffectStyle.Light
[image]

With UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark
[image]

With UIBlurEffectStyle.ExtraLight
[image]

Comment: Seems exactly what I have already do.. I have to see not blurred view inside the circle

Comment: I tried your solution, but I have different output, take a look to the update

Comment: I can't get same result.. I'm on Xcode8 with swift 2.3

Comment: I am using Xcode 7, swift 2.2. When i checked in xocde8,swift 2.3 it shows bit different result.

Comment: Damn.. If you find any solutions please notify me!

Comment: One solution is keeping one more image view behind at same level as of blur view and applying mask to viewBlur.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue in my code. After I applied the mask on the `UIView` containing `UIVisualEffectView`, the blur disappeared. However, I could turn it back by overriding the `draw` method on the parent:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
}
```

I don't know why it works exactly, but hope it will help someone. The code I used to cut the hole out:

```
private func makeViewFinderMask() -> CAShapeLayer {

    let path = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds)
    let croppedPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: viewFinderBounds(), cornerRadius: viewFinderRadius)
    path.append(croppedPath)
    path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true

    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    mask.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
    return mask
}
```